# Get all Discord Members with DiscordJs

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I try to get all members in a Discord server using the following code:

```
const memberList = await interaction.guild.members.fetch();
console.log(memberList)
```

If I run this I get a timeout.

I have heard that it is not optimal to fetch all members and it is more efficent to take them from the cache using the following code. However this respond only 2 people on the server to me.

```
interaction.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```

How can I get all members in the server? The plan is to check who have no role and kick them.

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with fetching all the members of the server if the server is not that big. Timing out when fetching is the result of not having the Guild Member's intent enabled

Comment: Ah okay thank you. What do you consider to huge to fetch the members. What would happend if I fetch them on a to huge server ?

Comment: That's somewhat of a gray area. If you want a member count, use `guild.memberCount`, if you want a random sample of all the members set a limit option on `fetch()`. There's usually a shortcut to fetching all members.